# Syncing Google Chrome on 2 devices

Tags: google-chrome

I have two devices that run Google Chrome (a Mac Mini and an MacBook Pro), and I would like to sync the bookmarks bar so that when one of them updates, it will then up date the bookmarks on the other device.

I have sync turned on in Chrome on both devices via Settings > Turn on Sync, but when I update my bookmarks tab on my Mac Mini, nothing happens on my Macbook Pro?

Any advice or guidance would be amazing.

Emily.

Comment: You are logged into the same account on both instances of Chrome?

Comment: hi @Ramhound yes I am.